# find center of circle from one point,knowing radius

Tags: circles

I have a problem that I have to solve. I need to find center of the circle containing the point $(x,y)$. The point is $x=2,y=3$ with radius $r=3$. I need to find the center of circle. Is there equation for that? I use this equation.
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$ 
How I can find $h$ and $k$ for the center of circle if I know the point on circle and the diameter of circle?

Comment: If you have a point on the circle and the radius, there are an infinite number of circles that this could be. You're going to need another bit of info.

Comment: You can't. Imagine a circle of specified diameter fixed at one point of the circumference. You can rotate the circle around this fixed point and the centre will follow...

Comment: Are you sure you have read the question correctly? I feel as though the question is actually asking for the equation of a circle with center $x=2,y=3$ that has radius 3. That would be exactly your equation with $h=2$ and $k=3$ and $r=3$: $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=4$.

Answer (score 1):

You have one equation in two unknowns, so should not expect a unique solution. Draw a circle around $(2,3)$ with radius $3$.  Any of the points on this circle could be the center of the circle you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to you $(x,y)$ is the centre with radius $3$ . So by the distance formula $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=3^2=9$. Then by plugging in any value for y you get a corresponding value for x. There are 2 unknowns and only 1 equation. So we need another parameter to solve for a specific point. Two, of the infinitely many, answers are for example: $(x,y)=(2,6)$ or $(2\sqrt{2},4)$.

Comment: "Acoording to you (x,y) is the centre." Where do you think the OP stated that?  The OP said x,y was a point on the circle, not the center.